# emacs: inverse search

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to do a inverse search?
I have very big log file where a particular pattern fills up for few dozen pages

```
20100414 alpha beta
20100414 alpha beta
<few dozen pages>
20100414 alpha beta
20100414 gamma delta
20100414 gamma delta
<few dozen pages>
20100414 gamma delta
```

Problem is, I don't know what text would be after "alpha beta". It could be "gamma delta" or something else. So I would like to skip all the lines that contain "alpha beta".

Comment: I found out this question using Google. My query was "emacs search first line that does not match". I think the text of the question is OK, and the answers are good. But I am not sure that the title of the question is the right one. I am not a native English speaker (I'm French), and "inverse search" for me means "backward search". Am I right? What could be a good title for the question?

Answer (score 7):

Two ideas:

1. `M-x keep-lines <RET> REGEXP <RET>`

   will remove all lines not matching a regexp
2. `M-x grep <RET> grep -nH -e "<REGEXP>" -v <FILE>`

   will find all lines in  NOT containing your regexp.

Comment: FWIW `flush-lines` does the opposite of `keep-lines` i.e. it deletes matching lines.

Answer (score 3):

You could use hide-lines: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hide-lines.el

Then `M-x hide-lines RET alpha beta RET` will hide all lines containing "alpha beta".

Now you can search using e.g. `C-s`...

Comment: It's similar to keep-lines and flush-lines, but it does not modify the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't do an inverse search, but for your particular case you could use a simple function:

```
(defun my-skip-lines-matching-regexp (regexp)
  "Skip lines matching a regexp."
  (interactive "sSkip lines matching regexp: ")
  (beginning-of-line)
  (while (and (not (eobp)) (looking-at regexp))
    (forward-line 1)))
```

then put in ".+alpha beta" for the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this by using a regexp search

```
C-u C-r ^20100414 [^a]
```

which searches for the next line that is "20100414 ", and that does the trick most of the time.  It'd find the "gamma delta" line, but would obviously miss a line that looks like "20100414 allegro".

There is also the command <kbd>M-x flush-lines RE</kbd>, which gets rid of *all* lines that match the regular expression `RE`.  This does modify the buffer.

Comment: @RyanThompson You surround the text with a 'kbd' enclosure like so: <kbd>something</kbd>.

Comment: How is this search excluding the tons of lines we want to search out ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks It searches for the first line that begins with '20100414' that is followed by something other than an 'a'.  Since his data is so structured, that essentially finds the first line that isn't "20100414 alpha beta" - obviously it'd skip "20100414 apple", so depending on how detailed you want to get you can customize the search string appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also search using `grep`, specifying that you want the lines that do *not* match.

You can also search using `icicle-occur`, using <kbd>C-~</kbd> to remove lines that match whatever you type.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic method that often proves to be useful is to jump to the end of the file and then search backward for the text you want to skip.  The success of this method obviously depends on the content of the file and works best when the repeating text in question occurs in singular chunks.